# vba code to send email based on dialog box answer

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

Here are the steps that I want to happen or something similar. I basically want a dialog box to cancel an email if special instructions were not reviewed:

1. The email is tagged with a Category named: Special Delivery. This is already done prior to everything.
2. I complete the job request and ready to send back a reply.
3. Click on "Reply All"
4. Email pops up, I can add attachments and body of the text etc...
5. When I click send I want a dialog box to pop up asking "Did you review delivery instructions?"
6. If I hit "OK", the email sends, if I hit "Cancel" the email closes and nothing is sent.

This is the code I'm using now; however, it sends the email regardless of what I click... Any help would be great.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If Item.Categories = "Special Delivery" And MsgBox("Did you review delivery instructions?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Take the `Item.Categories` out because the `Item` will not have Categories when your replying and use `vbOKCancel) = vbCancel`*

*Example*

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Prompt As String
        Prompt = "Did you review delivery instructions?"

        If MsgBox(Prompt, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly; however, the reason for the Item Categories is so that this doesn't pop up for every email I respond to.  Only certain emails I want this pop up to happen with.  So I created a Category in outlook called "Special Delivery".  This way only the dialog box will pop up for those emails marked with Special Delivery.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine which condition is the problem by separating them.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If Item.Categories = "Special Delivery" Then

    debug.print "Item has Special Delivery category"

    If MsgBox("Did you review delivery instructions?", vbOKCancel) <> vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

Else

    debug.print "If item has Special Delivery category it was not identified"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The first If statement gave an error immediately. I tried putting Then at the end and it doesn't do anything. The email responds like normal with no pop ups or anything.

Comment: I fixed my air code. Based on the results it seems reasonable to say, the immediate window would have displayed "If item has Special Delivery category it was not identified". If so, you will have to figure out another method of marking the mail.

Comment: Yea seems like marking the email is the issue here.  But all the codes above are very helpful.  I'll try to piece something together.